# error while receiving data and converting it into f64

Tags: python, tcp, byte

I am trying to send data over a TCP connection from rust to python, however while receiving the data in python I am getting the following error when trying to convert it from bytes to f64.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 36, in <module>
    [x] = struct.unpack('f', data)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I am using the follwoing method to convert the data from bytes to f64,

```
      [x] = struct.unpack('f', data)
        print(x)
```

my data looks like this, which I am sending over a tcp

```
x: 0.011399809271097183 (f64 from rust)
```

and getting something like

```
b'?t=*\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xbd\xc6\x80\x00\x00\x00?q\xd5s\x00\x00\x00\x00?|\xae\x85\x80\x00\x00\x00?e\xb5\xc3\x00\x00\x00\x00?yp;\x80\x00\x00\x00?p\x7f\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00?hG|\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\x8d&\x00\x00\x00\x00?cv[\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xdf\x97\x80\x00\x00\x00?{\x0e\xde\x80\x00\x00\x00?n\xec\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00?n\xd8E\x00\x00\x00\x00?y+\xdd\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xd90\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xc2\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00?q\xc2i\x00\x00\x00\x00?kq"\x00\x00\x00\x00?t5\xec\x80\x00\x00\x00?|\xaak\x80\x00\x00\x00?z\x10\x9d\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\xeb\xde\x00\x00\x00\x01?m6\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: This is not working, I guess in the line struct.unpack('f', data) need to specify that I am getting f64 , however I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: A single float64 is 8 bytes. That’s more than that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears 24 8-byte floats (`double` type in C) were sent in big-endian format.  At least the data appears as something reasonable, although none of them match the single value listed in the question:

```py
>>> data = b'?t=*\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xbd\xc6\x80\x00\x00\x00?q\xd5s\x00\x00\x00\x00?|\xae\x85\x80\x00\x00\x00?e\xb5\xc3\x00\x00\x00\x00?yp;\x80\x00\x00\x00?p\x7f\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00?hG|\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\x8d&\x00\x00\x00\x00?cv[\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xdf\x97\x80\x00\x00\x00?{\x0e\xde\x80\x00\x00\x00?n\xec\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00?n\xd8E\x00\x00\x00\x00?y+\xdd\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xd90\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xc2\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00?q\xc2i\x00\x00\x00\x00?kq"\x00\x00\x00\x00?t5\xec\x80\x00\x00\x00?|\xaak\x80\x00\x00\x00?z\x10\x9d\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\xeb\xde\x00\x00\x00\x01?m6\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> s
b'?t=*\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xbd\xc6\x80\x00\x00\x00?q\xd5s\x00\x00\x00\x00?|\xae\x85\x80\x00\x00\x00?e\xb5\xc3\x00\x00\x00\x00?yp;\x80\x00\x00\x00?p\x7f\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00?hG|\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\x8d&\x00\x00\x00\x00?cv[\x00\x00\x00\x00?s\xdf\x97\x80\x00\x00\x00?{\x0e\xde\x80\x00\x00\x00?n\xec\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00?n\xd8E\x00\x00\x00\x00?y+\xdd\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xd90\x80\x00\x00\x00?r\xc2\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00?q\xc2i\x00\x00\x00\x00?kq"\x00\x00\x00\x00?t5\xec\x80\x00\x00\x00?|\xaak\x80\x00\x00\x00?z\x10\x9d\x00\x00\x00\x00?o\xeb\xde\x00\x00\x00\x01?m6\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> len(data)
192
>>> len(s)/8
24.0
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>24d',s)
(0.004941143095493317, 0.004819655790925026, 0.004353951662778854, 0.007002374157309532, 0.0026501473039388657, 0.0062105488032102585, 0.00402793288230896, 0.0029637739062309265, 0.0038514845073223114, 0.0023757722228765488, 0.004851905629038811, 0.006605977192521095, 0.0037749987095594406, 0.003765234723687172, 0.006145348772406578, 0.004601659253239632, 0.004580054432153702, 0.004335794597864151, 0.003349844366312027, 0.0049342382699251175, 0.006998462602496147, 0.0063634999096393585, 0.003896649926900864, 0.003566257655620575)
```